# Newbie needing help in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

My current SQL statement is:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    names
WHERE   UPPER(first_name)                      LIKE UPPER('John Smith%')
OR      UPPER(last_name)                       LIKE UPPER('John Smith%')
OR      UPPER(first_name || ' ' || last_name)  LIKE UPPER('John Smith%')
```

I want to search my table for "John Smith", this SQL statement is okay.
But what if I have an entry with the first name as 'John Kevin' and last name 'Smith', this wouldn't include that entry. What do I need to add? Thanks all! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Similar To operator to cover all possible combinations.

```
Select * from table names UPPER(first_name || ' ' || last_name) 
SIMILAR to '%(UPPER(John)|UPPER(Smith))%';
```